# Why isn't it possible to do a subtotal over an integer in CL_SALV_TABLE?

Tags: abap, leading-zero, alv

Let's assume we have the following table in ABAP:

| PERNR | WORKHOURS | Other_Fields |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00012 | 12,00 | - |
| 00110 | 5,00 | - |
| 00120 | 22,00 | - |

PERNR is on its DB-table saved as a NUMC with leading 0's.
Due to some must-have-features, the leading 0's must be deleted **before** displaying a SALV-Table with CL_SALV_TABLE (as it is not accessible later on since). So essentially we have the following example data:

| PERNR | WORKHOURS | Other_Fields |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 12,00 | - |
| 110 | 5,00 | - |
| 120 | 22,00 | - |

Now I want to do the following:

1. Do a total over WORKHOURS
2. Do a subtotal over PERNR

But since PERNR is a NUMC, the result is the following:

| PERNR | WORKHOURS | Other_Fields |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 110 | 5,00 | - |
| 12 | 12,00 | - |
| 120 | 22,00 | - |

AFAIK, NUMC is getting compared from left to right and then this order makes sense. Sadly, I cannot change this, when I create my own dataelement for this or my own domain (At least I didn't saw an option to...).

When I cast PERNR as an INTEGER or DEC however, the **sorting** works and the order is as expected. Additionaly there is no need to delete leading 0's since these datatypes don't display or have leading 0's. **BUT** when I try to do my Steps 1. and 2., I get the following Error when trying Step 2. :
"Subtotals cannot be calculated on aggregatable columns"

...Why? I don't see a reason to not aggregate these values. I haven't found any documentation so far as to why this is not allowed (or possible) either.
I found numerous websites that explain, how to do it by coding it, but when I try to do a subtotal via coding I get the same error, so I'm pretty stuck.

Is it somehow possible to still do a subtotal over the column PERNR?

EDIT:
@Suncatcher Sry, I used a tabletype in my datadictionary and didn't wanted to make the Post too large. I'll try to define my coding here as short as possible.
Structuretype and Tabletype that has this as stucture defined:

```
@EndUserText.label : 'Structure for test salv'
@AbapCatalog.enhancementCategory : #NOT_EXTENSIBLE
define type ZS_SALV_STRUCTURE {
pernr        : abap.numc(8);
workhours    : abap.dec(4,2);
other_fields : abap.string(256);
}
```

Tabletype is called `ZT_SALV_STRUCTURE` in this example.
The Report is shortened as follows (Example where I delete leading 0's from NUMC):

```
REPORT zsalv_test.
DATA: gv_okcode TYPE sy-ucomm,
      gx_salv   TYPE REF TO cl_salv_table,
      gt_data   TYPE zt_salv_structure.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  "Example 1: Delete leading 0's
  "Create example data to substitute the CDS-View
  gt_data = VALUE #( ( pernr = '012' workhours = 12 other_fields = '-' )
                     ( pernr = '110' workhours = 5  other_fields = '-' )
                     ( pernr = '120' workhours = 22 other_fields = '-' ) ).
  "Delete leading 0's
  LOOP AT gt_data ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_data>).
    CALL FUNCTION 'CONVERSION_EXIT_ALPHA_OUTPUT'
      EXPORTING
        input  = <ls_data>-pernr
      IMPORTING
        output = <ls_data>-pernr.
  ENDLOOP.
  "Example 1 END

  "The Dynpro has gv_okcode for the OKCODE and is filled with a single custom container named 'CONTAINER'
  CALL SCREEN 0100.

*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*& Module STATUS_0100 OUTPUT
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
MODULE status_0100 OUTPUT.
  IF gx_salv IS INITIAL.
    cl_salv_table=>factory(
      EXPORTING
        r_container    = NEW cl_gui_custom_container( container_name = 'CONTAINER' )
        container_name = 'CONTAINER'
      IMPORTING
        r_salv_table   = gx_salv
      CHANGING
        t_table        = gt_data
    ).
    gx_salv->get_functions( )->set_all( abap_true ).
    gx_salv->get_columns( )->set_optimize( abap_true ).
    DATA(lt_columns) = gx_salv->get_columns( )->get( ).
    LOOP AT lt_columns ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_column>).
      CASE <ls_column>-columnname.
        WHEN 'PERNR'.
          <ls_column>-r_column->set_long_text( 'PERNR' ).
        WHEN 'WORKHOURS'.
          <ls_column>-r_column->set_long_text( 'WORKHOURS' ).
        WHEN 'OTHER_FIELDS'.
          <ls_column>-r_column->set_long_text( 'OTHER_FIELDS' ).
      ENDCASE.
    ENDLOOP.
    gx_salv->display( ).
  ELSE.
    gx_salv->refresh( ).
  ENDIF.

ENDMODULE.
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&      Module  USER_COMMAND_0100  INPUT
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
MODULE user_command_0100 INPUT.

ENDMODULE.
```

When I use INTEGER or DEC for PERNR, I change the Structuretype as follows and don't delete the leading 0's:
INTEGER:

```
pernr        : abap.int4;
```

DEC:

```
pernr        : abap.dec(8,0);
```

And I "cast" my data in my Consumption-View via the `CAST`-Expression INTEGER:

```
cast(PersonnelNumber as abap.int4) as pernr;
```

DEC:

```
cast(PersonnelNumber as abap.dec(8,0) as pernr;
```

As for how I am sorting and do a (sub-)total: I use the function provided by the CL_SALV_TABLE class on the dynpro while running the report (Small buttons on top of the SALV).

Comment: `When I cast PERNR as an INTEGER or DEC` how do you cast it? how do you sort? how do you calculate subtotals? so much fluff and no code snippet included

Answer (score 0):

Subtotal it's only on numeric data type. NUMC it's a char like field that allow only numbers but it's a char.

If you have this table...

| PERNR | Month | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0010 | Dec. | 160 |
| 0010 | Nov. | 100 |
| 0020 | Dec. | 80 |

You must have this Subtotals options
Group by PERNR

| PERNR | Month | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0010 |  | 260 |
| 0020 |  | 80 |

Group by Month

| PERNR | Month | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | Dec. | 240 |
|  | Nov. | 100 |

If you wanna show PERNR with zero leadings, you can force ALPHA as conversion exit in the fieldcat.

Best regards.

Sebastian

Comment: Could you clarify where I can set the fieldcat in the CL_SALV_TABLE class as I wasn't able to find a method that let's me do so. The closest thing I got was (in my code above) `r_column->` as it's functions resemble roughly the fieldcat parameters.
Also I don't want to display the leading zero's. That is the base problem; Don't display them, don't export them but still "use" the NUMC sorting logic.

Comment: You must use the `CL_SALV_COLUMN` instance. Here an example: [SALV Column use](https://answers.sap.com/questions/5852940/how-to-build-field-catalog-and-pass-to-clsalvtable.html)